# Searching data with typos in it in Solr

Tags: solr, nlp, lucidworks

I have found a lot of information on correcting misspelled search queries in Solr but I haven't found much in regard to the data Solr searches having typos in it. For example if I search for "dachshunds", is there a way to ensure I also return "dacshunds"? Is there a way to tune for some amount of "close enough" tolerance?

In essence I have a lot of hand written notes to search through and people misspell stuff all the time in notes. I want to have my search results return things that are pretty close to right without having to explicitly define those misspellings in synonyms.

Comment: You may want to look into Levenshtein distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which has had success handling misspellings. I'm pretty sure Solr has parameters you can adjust to that can help with this though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752301/how-to-configure-solr-to-use-levenshtein-approximate-string-matching